# How to put the STAR symbol into title of html page?

Tags: html, special-characters, title

I saw several sites have the star (some solid black, some white star) in their title tab. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: probably using its [UTF8 code](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm) &#x2605

Comment: Does i have to set font in somewhere before doing this?

Comment: just inserting into <title> element(or anywhere on page) should work

Comment: Gives us an example url of one of these sites please... You are not talking about the `favicon` ?

Comment: Now i can't find the site that have the star in title, and it's not a favicon. By the way, thanks.

Comment: ★ ☆ ✡ ✢ ✣ ✤ ✥ ✦ ✧ ✨ ✩ ✪ ✫ ✬ ✭ ✮ ✯ ✰

Comment: It 's not a favicon. It's a star includeing in title. I found that when I googled it, but I just can't remember what word i looked for or what sites.

Answer (score 7):

You can use various star symbols (there are many of them Unicode) either as such or as an entity reference inside a `title` element, e.g.

```
<title>☆ Hello world</title>
```

(if the character encoding of the document is UTF-8 and has been properly declared)
or, equivalently,

```
<title>&#x2606; Hello world</title>
```

However, the `title` element is rendered by browsers in special ways, normally using a font that depends on the operating system or on the browser, beyond author control. This means that the character repertoire can be rather limited in practice.

Comment: thanks Jukka K. Korpela but it's not work for me. You can see at http://www.whiewshop.com/Stars.html

Comment: As I wrote, it depends on the environment and on the browser. It works for me on IE, Firefox, and Chrome (on Win 7), but I know that in older systems, the character repertoire was rather limited. You need to describe the situation more exactly (what happens, on which browser[s], and do you really refer to what happens when visiting the whiewshop.com page) to get more detailed help.

Comment: I use windows 7 (32bit) and google chrome, the result is rectangular, and in IE8 it show the code instead of star.

Comment: This may depend on settings in Windows; if you set the font of certain UI components, you may end up with a font that does not render the stars properly. Regarding IE 8, it indeed fails to render `&#x2605` properly when a semicolon is missing (and XHTML rules unconditionally require the semicolon) as on whiewshop.com page, but this seems to happen in Quirks Mode only (and the default mode for the whiewshop.com page is “Standards Mode”).

Answer (score 4):

You mean this element?  ★

In your html:   `&#9733;` ,  or in js: `\u2605`

More info here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm

Comment: yes black solid star. It can show everywhere in the page, but not title.

Comment: I found several html codes for stars at http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb but I still can't put it to the title.

Comment: This works for me in Chrome:  <head>
<title>
 &#9733;
</title>
</head>

Answer (score 0):

You do know that you could have a look at the source of the web page to see how others are doing it?

But basically you want to insert the right [html entity](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp) in your title tag, e.g.

```
<title>&#10021; test symbol</title>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using (and which charset)? These could have an impact so you might want to choose a broadly-supported html entity.

Comment: Have to set the font in somewhere?